# Adding text over an image on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I want to make an iphone application similar to some greeting cards application, where I could write text over some pre prepared background images(cards).

- How can I write this text?
- How to save the background image+the text on one image file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Core Graphics could be the right direction.

Comment: you can make a blank controller with the status bar hidden and make a screenshot after finished editing. I think UIImagePNGRepresentation is what you need for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I think your solution is much more easier than using tha Core Graphics, I'll focus on that. If I understand, You mean I prepare the background image on a uiview and add a uiTextfield with transparent bachground on it, let the user input the text then make a scereenshot. Is That may be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a method that burns a string into an image.  You can tweak the font size and other parameters to configure it to your liking.

```
/* Creates an image with a home-grown graphics context, burns the supplied string into it. */
- (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[img drawInRect:aRectangle];

[[UIColor redColor] set];           // set text color
NSInteger fontSize = 14;
if ( [text length] > 200 ) {
    fontSize = 10;
}
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontSize];     // set text font

[ text drawInRect : aRectangle                      // render the text
         withFont : font
    lineBreakMode : UILineBreakModeTailTruncation  // clip overflow from end of last line
        alignment : UITextAlignmentCenter ];

UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
return theImage;
}
```

Comment: @Rayfleck I know this is an old answer, but I just found it today and it works great, so thank you! I've just got one question. Is there a way to modify this code to draw the string vertically?(text rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise)

Comment: @Ryan - first rotate the image CLOCKwise, then burn in the text, then rotate it back.  Look here http://www.catamount.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=967 for some handy UIImage extensions to do the rotations.

Comment: It is just returning a NULL image? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Rayfleck!  It worked.

To add optional compatibility with retina displays (fixes choppy letters during '@2x' version of image scale up):

replace:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
```

with conditional:

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size,NO,0.0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
```

Comment: Glad to help! The IF statement is a quick check to see if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (ios4 or later).  If not, then you can assume it's not retina.  If it is, then you are passing the options: 1 - size of image (text area); 2 - transparent background (opaque = NO); and 3 - '0.0' which tells the device to use its own scale (retina displays will default to 2.0(?))

Answer (score 0):

Update for ios7...

```
 /* Creates an image with a home-grown graphics context, burns the supplied string into it. */
    - (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

        CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
        [img drawInRect:aRectangle];

        [[UIColor redColor] set];           // set text color
        NSInteger fontSize = 14;
        if ( [text length] > 200 ) {
            fontSize = 10;
        }

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:fontSize];
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;


        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
        [text drawInRect:aRectangle withAttributes:attributes];

        UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   // extract the image
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     // clean  up the context.
        return theImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes in account the screen's scale and it's super intuitive

```
    UIImage * img = ...
    UIImageView * iV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    UILabel * l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:iV.bounds];
    l.textAlignment = ...;
    l.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    l.textColor = ...;
    l.font = ...;
    l.text = ...;

    [iV addSubview:l];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(iV.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [iV.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return finalImage
```